# Toshiba Laptop Hardware Failure

Tags: windows-10, boot, battery, toshiba-laptop

My laptop's I/O seemed to all just stop today. It was working fine one moment, and then the screen turns off (no backlight either), my mouse doesn't do anything, the keyboard doesn't do anything, even the lights on caps lock and num lock don't change when pressed. I was lucky to have a remote desktop set up so I could see the screen as it should have been. I was able to shut it down, but it wouldn't start back up when I pressed power, it just stayed off completely. I took out all peripherals and the power cable, and it still didn't turn on. When I took the battery out for about 30 seconds and put it back in, it was able to start up properly. Everything worked fine. I've had this laptop for a few years, and I worry this is a sign it may be no good anymore. What exactly happened and how do I fix it? I use a Toshiba laptop running Windows 10 if it helps.

Comment: If you're able to access the BIOS, look around if there is a diagnostics menu somewhere and start it. Or try their own [TOSHIBA PC Diagnostic Tool Utility](https://support.toshiba.com/support/viewContentDetail?contentId=4009373 "TOSHIBA PC Diagnostic Tool Utility") if you're still able to get into the OS. Next stop would be their [repair site](https://support.toshiba.com/repair) :-\ Good luck!

Comment: I couldn't find the Diagnostic Tool on Toshiba's page, but the Health Monitor said my battery health shows up as poor, which people say can lead to hardware failures. Could this have been he cause?